# No default constructor found

Tags: c++

I don't want to use the default constructor so I implement mine

```
class A
{
  public:
     A(int&i);
     A& operator=(const A& a);
     A(const A&a);
};
```

But in class B

```
class B
{
   A a;
   public:
     B(const A&a){this->a=a;}
}
```

Then the error:

> no appropriate default constructor of A found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the provided code [works](http://ideone.com/P080CF). maybe you need to elaborate a bit more

Comment: It's hard to be sure what you are asking. The code you provide works, so I assume there is somewhere that is requiring a default constructor for `A`. The error should take you to the line that requires it. In saying that: by defining any constructor, the compiler will not automatically generate a default constructor for you, so it sounds like you have what you want, you just need to work out where your code is trying to default construct an `A`

Comment: @Tas see the edit, the code doesn't compile.

Comment: You don't want to use a default constructor for `A`, but you *are* using it implicitly in `B`, by not invoking a different constructor for `A` in the constructor for `B`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a constructor initialization list, so the member `a` is initialized via the copy constructor:

```
B(const A&a):a(a){}
```

If you don't use a constructor initialization list, then the compiler first tries to initialize `A a;`, and only after assigns the other `a` to it. However, the first initialization fails because there is no default constructor provided. In general, it is recommended to always using the constructor initialization list when initializing members. In this way, instead of calling one constructor + one assignment operator, you only call the copy constructor.

I suggest changing the name of the member from `a` to e.g. `_a`, so the code becomes a bit more clear.